# Segmentation fault on 2D arrays of certain size

Tags: c, arrays

I'm creating a program with multiple threads where one of threads creates 2 matrices based on input. These inputs are n and seed. Input specifies the square size of the matrix (n x n size) while seed fills the matrices with the values starting from seed incremementally. The problem I'm having is that this function runs fine for inputs n = 1,2,3,4 but 5 and above causes a segmentation fault.

```
void *creatematrices(void *arg)
{

   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1); 
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2); 
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex3);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex4);  

   int seed;

   printf("To create two nxn matrices, A and B,first please enter the value for n\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("Now please enter the seed integer for the first element of matrix A\n");
   scanf("%d", &seed);

   A = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       A[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
   }

   B = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       B[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
   }

   C = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       C[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
           A[i][j] = seed++;
       }
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {   
           B[i][j];
       }
   }

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);

   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I'm using dynamic allocation for the 2d Arrays. I've realized this is probably a stack overflow error so I've already entered `ulimit -s unlimited` to no avail.

Comment: Can you show us how you call this function? It's not clear why the declaration takes `void* arg`, among other things.

Comment: it's a separate thread so `pthread_create(&th1, &attr, creatematrices, NULL);` is used to call it. If this were implemented not as a thread it would probably take the pointers A, B, and C as arguments.

Comment: You've got the `malloc` backwards. The first `malloc` should be allocating pointers using `sizeof(int*)`, and the second `malloc` should be allocating integers using `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: You're also locking four mutexes, but only releasing two.

Comment: Thank you you are 100% correct. Very silly of me. Do you have any idea why this would result in correct answers for smaller values though? Like I said this was working for n = 4.

Comment: Typically, `malloc` rounds up, e.g. only allocates in multiples of 16. So when you request a small amount of memory, you'll get more than you asked for.

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to help, good luck with the project.

Comment: if you use the pattern `p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);` then this problem could not occur

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `A` is of `int **A`

then you made a mistake in the mallocs:

```
A = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int)); // << wrong. It has to be sizeof (int*)
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   A[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int*)); // << wrong. It has to be sizeof (int)
}
```

In the above `A[i]` points to a memory pool which contains `n` pointers to int, so it must be dealt accodingly.

Same story with all other allocations.